# How do I toggle header/cpp file via keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'd like a simple keyboard shortcut to swap between the header (h, hpp) and CPP files. Visual Assist for Visual Studio allowed me to do this via <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. Is there a similar keyboard binding for Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? The only thing I can find is you can go to the .h from the source if you right click on a function and say goto source.

Comment: In Mai 2023 `alt-o` worked out of the box. It's also easy to remeber o like sOurce ;-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the extension [`ms-vscode.cpptools`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools) to `Switch Header/Source`.

- If you're on **Mac**, then the shortcut is **⌥ O** (option + O key).
- On **Windows**, the shortcut is **Alt+O**.

*Old answer:*

There are currently a couple of extensions that support header/source file toggling:

- [`bbenoist.togglehs`](https://github.com/bbenoist/vscode-togglehs)
- [`ryzngard.vscode-header-source`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryzngard.vscode-header-source)

You can find more by searching the words "switch toggle header source" in the extensions tab in vscode.

Answer (score 0):

In my case builtin IntelliSense solution conflicted with clangd plugin that I use, so the solution that worked for me was using aforementioned [Header source switch](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryzngard.vscode-header-source) plugin.

Comment: Just found it, `clangd.switchheadersource`. It's option+cmd+O, but it can be changed to option+O.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `clangd` plugin already, then you don't need an additional plugin and can use cmd-opt-o.

Answer (score -1):

No need for an extension, this is now built into Visual Studio.

The command you're looking for is:

```
EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.ToggleHeaderCodeFile
```

It's by default bound to Ctrl-K, Ctrl-O.

Comment: Sadly your answer is about Visual Studio but the question was about Visual Studio Code. Such a shortcut is currently not built into VS Code as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score -8):

Ctrl + Tab, press it one and it'll always swap between A.cpp and A.h file.

Comment: That's the shortcut in Eclipse